# Downloading PDF files using AJAX and POST

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

Hello guys I’m trying to make a web application with django to download pdf files. It seems to work fine if I use http://localhost/download, when I make these request it’s a GET request, I wonder if it’s possible to download a file but using AJAX and POST.

I need to use post because there is an AJAX request and that view process some data before to download the file, or maybe I have to use necessarily an independent url just to download files and using the GET method.

Is it possible?

I have tried but the browser does not download the file if I set:

```
If request.method = “POST”
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: Can you provide the client-side code in which you're performing the AJAX call?

Comment: If you make an ajax request (get or post) to get the PDF, then how will you tell the browser to "download" the file in the success: callback?

Comment: I think is not possible, am I right ?